# Finding a combination in a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to find a combination but it is not working

```
>>> whole = ('\n1. WIPO is located at\n(A) New York\n(B) London\n(C) Geneva\n(D) Paris\n')
>>> match = re.findall('1\.\s(\w+\s)+\w+\n', whole)
>>> print(match)
['located']
```

I want it to return `"1. WIPO is located at\n"`. But it is just returning `['located ']`

Answer (score 1):

Make the group *non-capturing*, using `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`:

```
re.findall('1\.\s(?:\w+\s)+\w+\n', whole)
```

If capturing groups are present, `re.findall()` changes behaviour and only returns the matched groups; with no captured groups the whole match is returned instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> whole = '\n1. WIPO is located at\n(A) New York\n(B) London\n(C) Geneva\n(D) Paris\n'
>>> re.findall('1\.\s(?:\w+\s)+\w+\n', whole)
['1. WIPO is located at\n']
```

If you only expect there to be the one match, then don't use `re.findall()` but use `re.search()` instead, and call `.group()` on the resulting `Match` instance:

```
>>> re.search('1\.\s(?:\w+\s)+\w+\n', whole).group()
'1. WIPO is located at\n'
```

Here, it no longer matters if the group is capturing or not.

Comment: So, in noobs' terms I've to put  '?:' in every capture after the '('  ? Can you explain what '?:' does?

Comment: @Ufoguy: Indeed; that is the syntactical difference between a capturing and a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Match Object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups).

```
print match.groups()
```